# R animated plotly: not resizing bubble when selection made via highlight

Tags: r, plotly, r-plotly

When creating an animated bubble plot bubbles are not changing size if selected using highlight.
Borrowing code from https://plotly-r.com/client-side-linking.html

```
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(gapminder) 

g <- highlight_key(gapminder, ~continent)

gg <- ggplot(g, aes(gdpPercap, lifeExp, 
      color = continent, frame = year)) +
      geom_point(aes(size = pop, ids = country)) +
      scale_x_log10()

p_gg <- highlight(ggplotly(gg), "plotly_click")
```

If select using plotly box the selected bubbles change size though the animation
[expected size](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m39Bz.png)

If select using hihlight plotly_click the selected bubbles don't change size in the animation
[size hasn't changed](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ycu7E.png)

Not sure if a bug or if I'm missing a setting